# Youtube iframe embed keeps disappearing from page

Tags: embed, youtube, iframe

I am trying to embed a video on my homepage.

I add the embed code from YouTube and paste it into a custom html blog on the gutenberg editor. I click update and check my website and the video is there.

I refresh the page and the video disappears. I go to the page editor and the embedded code for the video has been removed.

Please can someone tell me why this is happening? I have tried to research it online but it is bring up articles from over 5 years ago and the responses don't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I installed fresh WordPress, `Twenty Fifteen` theme on it, and embedded YouTube code. I didn't got any problem like this, I guess it must be some kind of `JS issue` you have or any-other problem.

FYI: I used `Gutenberg editor` too